# Linq Except on multiple class properties

Tags: c#, linq

What i have is the following:

Two list containing custom objects, these objects contain multiple properties, however i only care about two at this point Filename and MD5.

Now both lists contain objects that are the same, and objects that are different based on these properties, what i need to do, is get all objects from list a that

1. Do not exists in listB
2. Exist in listB, have the same Filename, but a different MD5

So the following:

**LIST A**

```
somefile.exe 1234
someotherfile.exe 5678
missing.exe 4321
```

**LIST B**

```
somefile.exe 1235
someotherfile.exe 5678
```

As such, the final list should contain

**LIST C**

```
somefile.exe 1234
missing.exe 4321
```

Now I've been advised that LINQ should be able to do this quite easily, but i cannot for the life of me work out how, I assume that except would work but all the examples i see use either numbers, or single properties.

Comment: If you have code, post it here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First implement [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) for your class and compare the objects based on the fields you are interested in.For example implement the `Equals` method like this:

```
public bool Equals(MyType a, MyType b)
{
    return a.FileName == b.FileName && a.MD5 == b.MD5;
}
```

Then just call `Except` method and pass your comparer:

```
var listC = listA.Except(listB, new MyEqualityComparer());
```

Or if you implement it on your class, instead of a separate comparer you can just call `Except`:

```
var listC = listA.Except(listB);
```

Be aware that you need also implement `GetHashCode` method.

Comment: Thanks, i cant believe i missed the ability to pass a custom comparer!